# Sails.js: best way to package DB and surrounding API models as module

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I'm new to Sails, but have used Express, and am considering Sails for my upcoming project. I particularly like that it makes the CRUD API for me and connects Socket.io automatically.

The next application I'm planning to work on has an indeterminate size; if it works well, we want to separate our CRUD/JSON API from our Web/HTTP server and load balance the Web/HTTP server. This would allow us to utilize the CRUD/JSON API in other adjacent applications, like code for statistical analysis, or external data parsers which import data, or other things which have nothing to do with Web/HTTP servicing.

In express I would consider making the API section a module then export the express.router with all the api calls like so

```js
//appAPI.js
var routes = require('express').router();

routes.get('/user/:id', function(request, reply){
    // assume db is connected database object 
    // and request.params.id is as expected
    db.getUser(request.params.id, function(u){
        reply.json(u);
    });
})

module.exports = routes;
```

```js
//app.js
var app = require('express')(),
    api = require('appAPI');

app.use('/api', api);
```

Then in my application, if I want to separate the Web from the API, I can package up the appAPI.js, and associated model code, and make a small connector to redirect all routes `/api/*` to the ip address and port of the api server, or other possibilities.

Can I do something like this in Sails? It seems that the automated model creation and the socket.io automation would make this difficult. Alternatively, I might be able to make a module for the API with a whole sails server then embed it in the main Web/HTTP server, which has its own sails objects running, but this seems like it either would not work, break the socket.io connections, or work, but be horribly inefficient as it would have multiple instances of sails running.

Any recommendations would be helpful and I'm willing to consider alternative ways of working this. Thank you all for any help you might provide and have a wonderful day.

Comment: So in essence are you saying, "I want to separate the front end of my app from the back end"?

Comment: yes, but using sails and it's generators. I want the web server part (serve html, js, css, socket) and controllers to be separable from the main portion of the model.